# Is there any possibility to recover the Bitlocker keys (32 digit) for the OS & data disks if Virtual Machine is not able to boot due to issues?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, iaas

Scenario- There is an Azure virtual Machine and the server is not able to boot due to any issues.

We need to recover the Bitlocker ID/Key (32 digit) & Password (48 digit) to recover the OS & data disks to boot and recover the server.
Please help to suggest the solution to recover Bitlocker Id/Password

We have tried to attach the managed disks created from OS & disk snapshots but since the server is down we are unable to provide the Bitlocker Password information.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to get the Azure VM Bitlocker keys from portal:**

I have created Azure Virtual Machine (**Windows Server 2019**) with **Bitlocker Encryption**.

[image]

You can recover **Azure VM Bitlocker** keys without logging to **Azure VM** from Azure Portal, even you can the fetch details if Server is down.

> Note: You can fetch Bitlocker key values only if VM joined to Azure AD/ Hybrid Azure AD.

**Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > Devices > All devices > Search Your Device**

[image]

Once open the device navigate to **BitLocker keys (Preview)**, and click on **show recovery keys** there you will find the device **Bitlocker Recovery Keys**.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am unable to see the bitlocker information from 
Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > Devices > All devices > Search Your Device. Only I am able to see the Properties, Roles and administrators & Administrative Units.

Could you let us know which solution needs to be enabled in Microsoft defender to view the Bitlcoker information.

Comment: If Encryption Keys are stored in Azure Ad while Bitlocker encryption, then only Bitlocker keys will reflect in Azure Portal.

Comment: Could you please let us know what kind of access/permissions we need to have to view the above Bitlocker Keys information from Azure portal

Comment: Security reader permission is required to view the Bit locker keys, refer this link more about permissions: http://blog.tofte-it.dk/azure-ad-access-to-bitlocker-recovery-keys/#:~:text=Azure%20AD%20%E2%80%93%20Access%20to%20BitLocker%20Recovery%20Keys,the%20ability%20to%20view%20Azure%20AD%20recovery%20keys.